# Toggle div and keep open

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some jquery to toggle a div to reveal some extra search fields on clicking a button. However those fields have an onchange event ("this.form.submit()" ) so every time they are used the div closes.

I guess I need to set some sort of cookie that keeps the div open until a reset button is pressed. The current script is

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function ($) {
var reveal_wrapper = $('.advancedsearch');
$('button.advancedsearchbutton').click(function () {
    $(this).toggleClass('open');
    reveal_wrapper.slideToggle(400);
    return false;
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: Can you JSFiddle this?

Comment: What are the onchange events? they shouldn't close it unless they are refreshing the page

Comment: Can you please also add your onchange event code?

Comment: onchange="this.form.submit()

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any cookie... You can use variables to keep the div open/close.
Every time your onchange event is called you can test the status of your div. In the event you can choose to close the div or open

Comment: When answering a question, a small code example is usually recommended to make it clear for other users.

Comment: CAn you give an example please

Comment: @tobiinformatik Just giving some tips on how to make a "good answer" so you can gain some rep ;)

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
$('button.advancedsearchbutton').click(function (e) {
    $(this).toggleClass('open');
    reveal_wrapper.slideToggle(400);
    e.stopPropagation();
    return false;
});
```

See more about `e.stopPropagation()` here: https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/

Comment: Thanks but that has no effect